# What is SciFi.SE's Elevator Pitch?

Tags: discussion

With respect to [Robert Cartaino's answer](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/155/this-site-is-doomed-and-will-curl-up-and-die-the-sunshine-and-hope-thread/189#189) on the hilariously-titled question, [This site is doomed and will curl up and die — the sunshine-and-hope thread](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/155), SciFi.SE needs to come up with an elevator pitch.

An [elevator pitch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elevator_pitch) is a short, 1-2 minute (although Robert suggests 5-10 seconds) schtick you can memorize and deliver to someone in an elevator when they ask, "What is the Science Fiction Stack Exchange site about?"

It's meant to distill down the core essence of the product so a person, before they get to their floor, fully understands what it is you're trying to do and, ideally, is convinced what you're trying to do is awesome and immensely worthwhile.

So what would be our elevator pitch? What is *quintessentially* SciFi.SE material, and what is *categorically* not? Why would a layperson who wasn't involved in the proposal ever want to visit and keep coming back?

Comment: I put together a set of links to the elevator pitch questions for the SE sites that have launched, in case anyone else wants to read them and doesn't want to search themselves: http://tonyandrewmeyer.wordpress.com/2011/02/10/pitching-scifi-stackexchange-com/ - however, note that these are the 5-10 seconds (at most - many are <1 second) variety.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## The Sci-Fi Insider's Guide

### Behind the scenes and between the lines

Wondering about those loose threads the series left you with?  We have the answers.

---

A few of us had a long conversation about this and basically agree that in order for this site to provide something both *useful* and *novel* (i.e. "make the internet a better place"), the motto/tagline/pitch needs to express three key concepts:

1. The site is for *serious, dedicated* fans of a work or series.  Good questions are normally about a *single* work or "universe", not *"What books should I read?"* recommendations or author bios.
2. Questions trivially answerable from a single primary or [canon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canon_%28fiction%29) source (i.e. one book, film, or episode) do *not* belong - hence "between the lines".
3. Questions are also not supposed to be entirely *speculative*.  In other words, something that's actually reasonably answerable either via supplementary sources (like the TNG Technical Manual) or clues left in the work itself (e.g. [Who Killed Asmodean?](http://www.cs.man.ac.uk/%7Efellowsd/jordan/asmodean-notable.html)).

This represents a considerable change from the style of question that's been asked so far and also represents a very specific niche; however, it is the best way to make the site *unique* and keep questions at what could reasonably be called an *expert* level (a requirement for all Stack Exchanges).

Comment: With regard to point 2: perhaps "questions **wholly** answerable from..." such sources are what should be banned. If a question requires putting together research with expert/enthusiast knowledge, then it might be a good question.

Comment: Speculation: I agree with your stance on this. There will always be some speculation in putting the pieces together, but let's try to ground it in the facts/explanations as given in the works in question. We should reverse the polarity of the neutron flow in a *consistent* manner! :)

Comment: @neil: There's probably some ambiguity in the language; when I said "trivially answerable" I did not mean "able to post a trivial answer" (as you probably interpreted it) but rather "trivially easy to answer".  In other words, if the answer is blindingly obvious just from *watching* episode 3, it's a low-value question.  I don't mind editing this answer but keep in mind that everything below the fold is just my personal notes and explanation, not necessarily intended to accompany the pitch itself.

Comment: @Aaronaught - Perhaps that can be looked at as the part of the pitch you could get into *if you had more time*. Looking at the above-the-fold part: "the word "series" says to me "TV series", although there's no reason it can't mean movies or books.

Comment: This seems like a basis for good questions, but can it generate sufficient original questions? Serious fans are probably already participating on sites specifically dedicated to the works they are fans of, and have compiled extensive pages of analysis based on the primary sources, so what will bring them here?

Comment: @sdobie: You could pretty much say that about *any* topic.  But do those people do it in a good Q&A format that's easy to find, or is it strewn about various forums and blogs?  I find your comment a little silly given that the majority of mindless trivia and list-building questions here are the furthest thing imaginable from being *original*.  If you want this site to compete with other SF boards then the smartest thing you can do is carve out a niche to minimize that competition.

Comment: @Gilles: Did you even read any of this post?  The whole point is that the site (not "my site") is **not** supposed to be for trivia.  Trivia adds no value, and it's not something that real enthusiasts would be interested in.  In order for a site like this to survive it has to answer questions that you *can't* already answer with a 5-second Google search or by just watching the movie.

Comment: *(expanded from my earlier deleted comment)* So your site is a trivia site: a site to discuss fine points of specific works. I think this can work, as a site for fans of popular series, especially since you're excluding trivially-findable trivia. But it's definitely not what I'm interested in.

Comment: @Gilles:  **No, it's not a trivia site.** Come on man, read the whole thing!

Answer (score 4):

### SF discussion sites, the “good parts” version

- [Read a story thirty years ago and can't remember its title?](http://groups.google.com/group/rec.arts.sf.written/browse_frm/thread/1a7f4f7a328c66d4/0c80b2b46334395a?tvc=1#0c80b2b46334395a)
- [Troubled over a plot point?](http://groups.google.com/group/rec.arts.sf.written/browse_frm/thread/5e92cbffd4d23302/23a1d6c85d6ba92f)
- [Not getting an allusion in a Pratchett book?](http://groups.google.com/group/alt.fan.pratchett/browse_frm/thread/df4803193b51696a/bdf2ff4f3a6c52e5)
- [Wondering how a hard sf concept could play out?](http://groups.google.com/group/rec.arts.sf.science/browse_frm/thread/e0b23f9fad17bea9)
- [Looking for information on the industry?](http://groups.google.com/group/rec.arts.sf.fandom/browse_frm/thread/59455d9ad53cb0b8/5103544015f42e65)

The questions and answers format and the voting system highlight the good stuff, prevent off-topic or meandering discussions and keep away spam.

*(Only pick one or two bullet points unless you're going to a very high floor.)*

---

Note that this represents what I think would be a good Science Fiction Stack Exchange site. I do not think it represents what scifi.se is at the moment.

Comment: The hard sf concept angle is perhaps the only cream in that crop

Comment: I think "help me remember" questions are generally a no-no for most SE sites.

Comment: @Final: see [my view on “help me remember” questions on the relevant Meta thread](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/13/are-book-movie-tv-series-identification-questions-allowed/22#22). I think it's the one thing that's absolutely needed for a successful SF.SE.

Comment: I'm not disagreeing at all. I think the ban is ridiculous. But it seems to have come from on high.

Comment: The word "discussion" does not belong in the elevator pitch/tagline for **any** Stack Exchange.  This pitch says *nothing* of substance, and the fact that one of the examples is literally officially banned across the network makes it one of the worst pitches I've ever heard.  I agree with @Eight, the Hard SF one is one example that's decent, but the pitch itself only seems to highlight the serious scoping problem here, not solve it.

Comment: @Aaronaught: On “discussion”: that's the whole point of “the ‘good parts’ version” — but if you have a good suggestion for a different word (not a phrase that's not immediately comprehensible like “questions and answers site”), please contribute. On the ban on identification questions: where do you get that it is banned? You're not the first to tell me this, but no one seems to have a source (FAQ entry? Meta post? Blog post?).

Comment: See [What is the point of “help me remember this game” questions?](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/q/1455) for the origin of that policy.  I think people presented some decent counterarguments and am not necessarily of the mind that there should be an *all-out ban*; however, it's really a very poor example to use for the pitch.  Even if the questions aren't *banned*, they should be *discouraged*.  See [The Pee-Wee Herman Rule](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/the-pee-wee-herman-rule/).

Comment: As for contributing something of my own, I really honestly wish I could.  I'm eagerly watching the front page for something worth using as an example or even upvoting, but it all seems to be lists and trivia.  I was interested in this SE too, from its Area 51 origin, but now that I'm actually seeing it play out, I just can't see the point.

Comment: @Gilles - I agree with a lot of the reservations here, but thanks for trying! Giving us something to tear apart is a great way to get started.

Comment: @Aaronaught and others: [There is no ban on identify-this questions.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76005/are-identify-this-questions-allowed-on-stack-exchange/76024#76024)

Comment: That is exactly what I said, @Gilles; no outright ban, but strongly discouraged.  Respected contributors may get a free pass once in a while, but you don't want to *sell* the site on that basis.

Comment: @Aaronaught: On the contrary, I do want to sell the site on that basis. [It works for other SF discussion sites](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/13/are-book-movie-tv-series-identification-questions-allowed/22#22), and it's ideally suited to the Q&A format.

Comment: The whole point is that Stack Exchange isn't a discussion site. If this site is nothing more than a recommendation service and simple trivia, it has little value

Comment: I agree with you for the most part, but it's a great format for other things, like Stack Overflow. Apparently it's going to fail for this subject.

Comment: It's fun to look at this from a "five years later" perspective. The fourth bullet point got moved to Worldbuilding, where it is *much* better suited.

Answer (score 1):

**DVD extras meet user generated content.**

Imagine if you could set the questions on the DVD extras for your favourite TV show or movie – or if you had extras for your favourite book.

You get answers about **what**, **how** and **why** things happened both in-universe, and in reality, from people who are intimately familiar with not just that one work, but the entire science fiction and fantasy genres – people that can pull together expert and interesting answers about how this work relates to other genre fiction and to the world. They’ll even explain what stories you should move to next if you loved particular aspects of this one.

<sub>Note that this is community wiki for anyone that would like to improve it.</sub>

Answer (score 1):

Since we include Fantasy in our site, I think we should review our Tagline, so here's my proposal.

### From Dragon To Aliens