# How should we handle questions that are easily answered by Wikipedia?

Tags: discussion, general-reference

Examples:

- [What is filk and how do I find it?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/439/what-is-filk-and-how-do-i-find-it) (see **[Filk](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filk)**)
- [What exactly were the Prophets?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/1598/what-exactly-were-the-prophets) (see **[Prophets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prophet_%28Star_Trek%29)**)
- [What is the precise definition of 'Steampunk'?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/78/what-is-the-precise-definition-of-steampunk) (see **[Steampunk](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steampunk)**)
- (and even the super-upvoted) [Who or what was Tom Bombadil?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/1586/who-or-what-was-tom-bombadil) (see **[Tom Bombadil](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tom_Bombadil)**)

What should we do?

1. Answer them with a link?
2. Answer them with a copy / paste?
3. Answer them with our own words?
4. Close them?
5. Something else?

Please can we establish a rule for this.

*Note: if you don't agree with one of my examples above write it in the comments by all means but note that this question is about the **principle** of what we should do.*

Comment: The *Tom Bombadil* question is a poor example.  Compare the question and its answers with the information on Wikipedia.  Our data here is far superior, and includes much that Wikipedia does not.

Comment: @Tony - thing is, do we want to compete with Wikipedia? Maybe we should go over there and update that entry, or add a link *there* to the question *here*... =:-)

Comment: I think the SE model has a lot of benefits over the Wikipedia one, so I would rather answer/ask/read here, personally. I don't see how asking a question here leading to updating Wikipedia is a viable model.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Increasingly, to a point where it's becoming ridiculous, any question that I have unless it's a question about a non-English speaking area (Québec, France, Spain, etc.) is easily answered by Wikipedia. Basically, almost anything that falls within Wikipedia's systemic bias can probably be answered by Wikipedia.

I think that all questions should pass the following test:

[image]

When it says "close as 'general reference'", it's referring to [this possibly new close option](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/197/should-trivially-easy-to-find-be-a-benchmark-for-moderating-the-site/220#220) that Jeff brought up. Until it's implemented, or if it's not implemented, read that as "close as "off-topic.'"

Comment: @Borror0 - I *nearly* agree - but at the top I think you should write **Google / Wikipedia**. Otherwise, pretty good!

Comment: @Wikis: That would only be redundant. If the answer can be found on Wikipedia, there's pretty good chance that Google will show you the relevant page in the top five results.

Comment: @Borror0 - yeah, you're right. I just tested my four examples and the Wikipedia entry was the *first* for 3 of the 4 responses - but not "Prophets" - that was *another* Wikipedia page! :)

Comment: this flowchart is great!

Comment: @Jeff - it is - it should probably be on all sites! @Borror0 - nice one.

Comment: I'd like to see a fancied up version of the chart in the FAQ. All of the FAQs.

Comment: This goes in my folder of "general reference" bookmarks. Nice!

Comment: I've just posted a link to this chart on Seasoned Advice. (http://meta.cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/1023/should-general-reference-questions-be-asked-and-answered-here/1024#1024)

Comment: @MarthaF.: I just fixed the typo in the previous version, if you want to use the fixed version.

Comment: your answer is featured in http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/02/are-some-questions-too-simple/

Comment: Just to let you know, Borror0, that I've posted this answer [over at Christianity SE](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/2027/what-is-the-c-se-equivalent-of-what-have-you-tried/2066#2066) as well. Thanks again for this great flowchart.

Comment: This looks good, but it should be noted that the last step is very subjective. No one should get upset because they think a question is trivial and uninteresting, but others want it open to answer it.

Answer (score 2):

Joel was always of the opinion for Stackoverflow that asking and answering questions found easily found elsewhere was perfectly fine, in fact encouraged, as it made SO a more comprehensive compendium of knowledge

Comment: should that be linking to the information or copy/pasting? Also, I guess that was back in the SO early days. Now, does that still apply to sites like this one?

Comment: @ Wikis At Area 51 I would personally say it was redescribing the information rather than regurgitating or linking (though maybe provide a link as well). As for its relevance in the other sites, you'd really have to ask Joel, as I was basically stating his opinion

Answer (score 2):

There is now a new experimental close reason, as previously discussed:

> #### general reference
>
> This question is too basic; it can be definitively and permanently answered by a single link to a standard internet reference source designed specifically to find that type of information.

Give that a try; we're evaluating the results. Also refer to the blog post on the topic with its handy chart:

http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/02/are-some-questions-too-simple/

Answer (score 2):

The problem with those question is not only about the fact that they could be answered by Wikipedia, **it's about the nature of the question**.

When the question is the only subject of an article on Wikipedia on a universe-specific wikis (Who is X, What is Y), the answer to the question is a single link, that fully, completely and easily answer the question. The answer to those questions is encyclopedic information and, I don't think it would be useful to repeat the content of Wikipedia or those universe-specific wikis on this site.

Answer (score 0):

I think that a combination of option 3 followed by option 1 or 2 would be best.

Anyone can Google for the answer, so people (should) come here with the idea of getting an expert or group opinion, along with sparking some discussions which defend or prove an answer. That implies option 3, right? Maybe to back up your answer you can post a link as a reference... like a "Would you like to learn more?" thing.