# Is a question "General Reference" if it requires several articles to be answered?

Tags: discussion, general-reference

The close reason for General Reference says:

> This question is too basic; it can be definitively and permanently
>   answered by a single link to a standard internet reference source
>   designed specifically to find that type of information.

Ok, but what about cases where it takes several links to reference source sites? If the question can be answered with a single Wikipedia link it is obvious, but is it still General Reference if it takes several articles? The answer in that case is derived from all those sources - it has an added value.

The main reason I ask this is because I asked a question [Why did they name the movie "Blade Runner"?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/20977/why-did-they-name-the-movie-blade-runner)  and it was closed as General Reference and I'm not sure if it should have been.

In any case, I'd like to know the community stance on the general question - is a combination of multiple links to standard internet reference sources a General Reference itself.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [this answer](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/330/4383) and [this blog](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/02/are-some-questions-too-simple/). They both post a flowchart describing when to close a question as general reference:
[image: Flowchart for Closing as General Reference]

When I looked up the answers to your question I found that (1) the answer could be found easily in the first few results, (2) that it was in no need of further improvement, and was not too hard to parse, (3) and was basic and trivial. This led me to VTC as General Reference.

Comment: But this flowchart (and the other one) make my point. An answer scattered across several lengthy articles does need improvement - criterion number 2.

Comment: The link I gave went right to the Production section where the answer is, which contained 6 paragraphs (hardly lengthy). Or, if you did a search for the word "name" within the article, there were only 3 instances, one of which pointed at the answer. The second link that answers your sub-questions only has 6 *sentences* (again hardly lengthy). I gave you the two specific links, but even when I first looked for the answer *without the links* it took me 30 seconds to completely answer your question. That *screams* General Reference to me.

Comment: @GoranJovic: a simple Google search brings relevant links in the top results, each independently and clearly answering your question. For example, Wikipedia and IMDb both clearly answer it.