# What are standard internet reference sites for SF?

Tags: support, faq, general-reference

What are [standard internet reference sites](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/02/are-some-questions-too-simple/) for science fiction and fantasy?

Comment: For discussions about our general reference policy, please see [What sites should be considered general references?](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/q/689)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

- [**Wikipedia**](http://www.wikipedia.org/), the famous online encyclopedia
- [**IMDB**, the Internet Movie Database](http://www.imdb.com/), a database about movies and TV shows
- [**ISFDB**, the Internet Speculative Fiction Database](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/index.cgi), a bibliographic database of written sf

*If you ask about an actor, author, book, movie, shows, etc, and the answer is clearly visible on the entry for that actor/author/… on one of these references sites, then your question will be [closed as too basic](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/197/should-trivially-easy-to-find-be-a-benchmark-for-moderating-the-site).*

Comment: and don't forget [Google.com](http://www.google.co.com/)

Comment: @hubeza google is a search engine, not a reference site. In some cases answers are directly in the page, but I cant think of any SF/F related cases.

Answer (score 11):

### Per-universe wikis

An answer appearing on these sites is not reason by itself to close as general reference; however if a link to a page with the answer appears high in search engine results, and the page doesn't need improvement (with respect to the question), then a "general reference" vote may be appropriate.

These sites *are* particularly useful for researching answers to questions within these universes; often a good answer will draw from material here (and elsewhere), and may refer the reader to more detailed (wiki-style) material on these sites.

<sub>(grouped by original media type)</sub>

#### Books

- *Dune* (Frank Herbert): [Dune Wiki](http://dune.wikia.com/)
- *A Song of Ice and Fire* (G.R.R. Martin): [A Wiki of Ice and Fire](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/) at [Westeros](http://www.westeros.org/)
- Terry Pratchett (Discworld and the rest): [L-Space](http://www.lspace.org/) ([wiki](http://wiki.lspace.org/))
- Orson Scott Card: [Ansible](http://ansible.wikia.com/)
- *Harry Potter* (J.K. Rowling): [Harry Potter Wiki](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/)
- J.R.R. Tolkien: [Lord of the Rings Wiki](http://lotr.wikia.com/), [Encyclopedia of Arda](http://www.glyphweb.com/arda/), [Tolkien Gateway](http://tolkiengateway.net/)
- Harry Turtledove: [Harry Turtledove Wiki](http://turtledove.wikia.com/)

#### Movies

- *Star Wars*: [Wookiepedia](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Main_Page)
- *Terminator*: [Terminator Wiki](http://terminator.wikia.com/)

#### Television

- *Battlestar Galactica*: [Battlestar Wiki](http://en.battlestarwiki.org/)
- *Doctor Who*: [Tardis Data Core](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/Doctor_Who_Wiki)
- *Farscape*: [Farscape Enyclopedia Project](http://farscape.wikia.com/)
- *Futurama*: [The Infosphere](http://theinfosphere.org/)
- *LOST*: [Lostpedia](http://lostpedia.wikia.com/wiki/Main_Page)
- *Primeval*: [Primeval Wiki](http://primeval.wikia.com/)
- *Stargate*: [Stargate Wiki](http://stargate.wikia.com/)
- *Star Trek*: [Memory Alpha](http://memory-alpha.org/) for canon, [Memory Beta](http://memory-beta.wikia.com/) for non-canon

#### Radio

- *The Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy* (Douglas Adams): [The Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy](http://hitchhikers.wikia.com/)

Comment: Note that the top four of these had their own Area51 proposals before being merged here.

Comment: The guidance from SE as to what is "standard" appears to be whether the site shows up in the first few results in a web search. Against that standard, IIRC all of these would apply.

Comment: While theoretically a good idea, Slytherincess and others have noted that the Harry Potter wikia sometimes adds information without references, and I've had times where information on Memory Alpha was difficult to find without already knowing the answer to a question (ended up fixing a link based on an answer here).  So for most of these, I'd say, they should be used as a reference while creating an answer, but not a reason to close as general reference.

Comment: @Izkata Did you read the first sentence or the second paragraph of the answer?  That's essentially what I said.  Note that the answer is also a year and a half old, and dates from the time when general reference was a new thing.

Comment: Ah, oops..  Been a while, but I think the two titles threw me off:  "What are standard internet reference sites for SF?" / "Per-universe wikis".  But I do remember, I hadn't realized just how old it was, because it was linked from the recent Rules of Acquisition question.

Comment: Many of these are somewhat unreliable and inaccurate.

Comment: I would not says these are "standard" refenece sites. I've never heard of 98% of them, and when I was a new SE user I didn't even know about per-universe wikis - so I don't think these should be _expected_ to be used as _standard_ references for asking questions.

Answer (score 2):

Not yet completed, but the 3<sup>rd</sup> edition of the [Encyclopaedia of Science Fiction](http://www.sf-encyclopedia.com/) will be on-line and free.