# Where can I ask questions that aren't Science Fiction & Fantasy Stack Exchange questions?

Tags: discussion, faq, site-rec

### Thank you for your confidence in our abilities!

But have you read our [FAQ](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/faq)?

This site is for [**questions and answers**](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/about) about science fiction, fantasy and more generally speculative fiction. This is not a free-form discussion site, so not every form of question fits. In particular, requests for a list of works with certain characteristics ([“list questions”](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16/are-list-questions-allowed)) are not appropriate, and neither are personalized reading recommendations (“what should I read next?”).

- For questions about **writing**, ask on [Writing Stack Exchange](https://writing.stackexchange.com/).
- For questions about building your own fictional world, ask on [Worldbuilding Stack Exchange](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/).
- For **simple factual** questions, consult a [general reference site](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/403/what-are-standard-internet-reference-sites-for-sf) first.

Check out the answers below for even more suggestions!

---

What forums can people go to to ask the questions that are off topic here, or just start discussions about SF topics? Please list only ONE forum per answer so votes can bring the best forums to the top.

Comment: This is modeled on [SO](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8401/where-can-i-ask-questions-that-arent-stack-overflow-questions), [SU](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/855/where-can-i-ask-questions-that-arent-super-user-questions) and [SF](http://serverfault.com/questions/1504/where-can-i-ask-questions-that-arent-it-questions). We've [briefly discussed it in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/673397#673397).

Comment: [I'm really confused](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/328489/323179) about how I added the [featured] tag to this question, but it's not like they can take away my diamond when *I don't have one*!

Answer (score 5):

#### TV Tropes

[TV Tropes](http://tvtropes.org/) collects [tropes](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/Trope), that is, recurring devices that writers expect their audience to recognize. Tropes become [clichés](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/Cliche) if they're overused. TV Tropes is a [wiki](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/WikiMagic), with [no notability requirement](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/ThereIsNoSuchThingAsNotability).

If you're looking for a list of works that have used a particular 
[plot element](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/Plots), [setting](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/Settings), [character](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/Characters) [type](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/CharactersAsDevice), [motif](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/Motifs) or other [narrative device](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/NarrativeDevices), then [check it out in the trope index](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/Tropes). Or you can browse by [genre](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/GenreTropes), [media](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/Media), [etc](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/HomePage).

Comment: How has this answer existed for over a decade without a single black hole warning? Do we just lose people into said black hole and say "eh, never mind"? :D