# Translations of fictional languages to English

Tags: discussion, scope

Specifically, when the fictional language is used in places outside of the works they appear in:

[What does this elvish text from UC Irvine say?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/96996/what-does-this-elvish-text-from-uc-irvine-say) is okay

[Grammar and quality check for a Klingon warning notice for server room](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/118448/grammar-and-quality-check-for-a-klingon-warning-notice-for-server-room) is a current question, has 3 close votes at the moment

[Is this Gallifreyan, and what does it say?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/103378/is-this-gallifreyan-and-what-does-it-say) is a surprising request because there's so little to go on, but it had an answer

[What is written on my Mjolnir?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/116583/what-is-written-on-my-mjolnir) is about a licensed product with runic gibberish

There may be more, I only looked through the first couple pages of a search for "translate", and they may have appeared in other ways.

It may not be enough to be too concerned about, but with one such question locked by a CM (I think the context was not good on that one, but that could be edited out), and a current one getting a close vote, I'm wondering about how to vote.

Answer (score 18):

I see no reason to consider these questions undesireable:

- **They're not off-topic.** These questions are asking about fictional languages from science fiction or fantasy contexts; that seems thoroughly under our umbrella.
- **They're not primarily opinion-based.** There's always going to be a single, unambiguously correct answer: either the correct translation or some variation on:

  > It doesn't mean anything; here's a statement from the creator saying they just took random symbols and mashed them together

  If there's no translation guides available, then we're asking if we should close a question because it has no canon answer, something [we are opposed to](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3014/should-all-questions-without-explicit-canon-answers-be-closed).
- **They're not too broad.** Depends on the question, obviously, but I fail to see how a single translation could fall under this.
- **They're not unclear.** For the most part, anyway.
- **They take advantage of the expertise we cultivate.** Our knowledge domain is the sum published output of science fiction and fantasy media, and the behind-the-scenes and fandom context surrounding that media. We are the *perfect* people to address questions about this sort of thing, and I struggle to think of anyone better suited.

Comment: `"We are the perfect people"` YEAH WE ARE!

Comment: I agree with everything you said, however I can't stop feeling it's... weird-ish. I'm not sure if a "Fictual Language" tag wouldn't actually help sort things out

Comment: On other language sites such as ELU, translations are off topic. Don't know if the same concept hold true here.... but every translate question would only be  specific to  that user and even though I am new here, I think SE wants QA that applies to all.

Comment: @Skooba All translation questions are not necessarily off-topic on ELU, either. “Please translate this long Spanish paragraph into English” is off-topic there (that's what translators are for), but “Which of X and Y fits better as a translation of Spanish Z?” is perfectly all right there. Similarly for most other language-specific SE sites that I know of. It's also a lot harder to find material for fictional languages, which invalidates the most common reason for grammar-check questions (on ELU at least): lack of prior research.

Comment: I've actually had 2 translate questions myself, [one for Latin to English](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/89991/in-iron-man-2-what-does-black-widow-say-to-tony-stark-in-latin) and one for [bad Russian to English](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/112330/what-does-oliver-queen-say-in-russian). So, we don't seem to have a policy against real language translations, either.