# Why was the Sifo-Dyas question closed as general reference?

Tags: discussion, general-reference, specific-question

[Who was Sifo-Dyas?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/4830/who-was-sifo-dyas) was closed as general reference. The general reference here seems to be the [Star Wars Wiki page](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Sifo-Dyas). Hmm, ok, but the asker evidently expected an answer relating to the movies, not the expanded universe, and it came as a bit of a surprise that he had to reach for non-movie material to get an answer. I don't see how that reference explains this clearly.

Related meta discussion: [What sites should be considered general references?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/689)