# Why was this "Rules of Acquisition" question closed?

Tags: discussion, closing-questions, vote-to-reopen

Maybe I'm hyper-sensitive to this, but I'm smelling a bias against certain [users](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/5404/rondo) who seem to have a name in common with a certain time-travelling robots troll <strike>(maybe it's even the same user, but I can't tell because I don't have access to moderation tools and can't see what questions were deleted -- anyway, **it doesn't matter**)</strike> (it does seem to be the same user (see the edit history), but that still **doesn't matter**).

---

This question:

- [Is there a list available of all of the rules of acquisition?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/21044/2565)

Seems perfectly on topic: The spirit of "list questions are bad" just wants to prevent bad subjective questions with *endless* lists, based on opinion or speculation. Especially, these sorts of lists are unable to be *accepted* properly (for obvious reasons).

This question doesn't qualify. It asks for *one* answer which entails providing a list of items, not a list of answers.

I do not buy that this is general reference either, because Wikipedia doesn't bother to name the source for most entries so it's impossible to *verify them as canon*.
The last time I checked memory-alpha, that list was vastly incomplete, too.

---

Currently, I count one single diamond vote-to-close, while there are three vote-to-reopen.

**Edit**: Also, the mod who closed this, [accepted a meta-answer](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/403/2565) indicating that **only** the Wikipedia article could be a candidate for general reference. So the memory-alpha article is out. And the Wikipedia article lacks references.

Comment: Additionally, the talk page on Wikipedia indicates the list isn't stable at all; Wikipedia editors can't seem to agree as to which ones to keep on there...

Comment: The Memory-Alpha page has a list of rules of acquisition. It is an easily Googled answer.

Comment: @JackBNimble: I was just recently lectured that [memory-alpha does not count as general reference](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/1022/what-two-tng-episodes-does-ashley-judd-appear-in-and-does-she-say-she-didnt#comment38291_1022).

Comment: @JackBNimble: See my edit, please.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I closed the question as *general reference* because the obvious Wikipedia article seemed to answer the question. Given further information, it seems that while the Wikipedia article technically answers the question as stated, there is more to say about the subject. So I have edited the question and reopened it.

Aside: When you see a bad question that leads to an interesting answer, don't just sit there and complain about closing. **EDIT THE QUESTION TO IMPROVE IT!**

Comment: Yes, I actually do edit questions from time to time. But when I first saw the question I, thought it was fine.

Comment: I did edit it down, and also thought the rest was fine as it was, if a little oddly phrased.