# Why are asking for lists or questions similar to asking for lists "bad"?

Tags: discussion

Aren't they legitimate questions? For example, "What episodes in Star Gate reference the 9th seal?" Let's say the answer is episode 1, 5, 20.

Please list the reasons... :P

See also,
[Are questions looking to simply prove or disprove a premise with a yes/no answer a good fit for our site?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1450/are-questions-looking-to-simply-prove-or-disprove-a-premise-with-a-yes-no-answer?rq=1)

PS Are they always closed?

Comment: Yes, they're always closed. The mods wield the CloseHammer quickly and furiously.

Answer (score 1):

If the question is suitably scoped then a question with an answer in the form of a list should be fine.  [Is there a list available of all of the rules of acquisition?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/21044/is-there-a-list-available-of-all-of-the-rules-of-acquisition) is a good recent example - while it was closed ( [Why was this "Rules of Acquisition" question closed?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2091/why-was-this-rules-of-acquisition-question-closed) ) it was closed because it was thought to be general reference, *not* because it was a list question.

The problem is with open-ended list questions or those with a huge scope.  These either cannot or will not be answered with a conclusive answer, instead resulting in a whole lot of short answers that list a single or handful of works that fit the category.

Comment: So close ended list questions are ok?

Comment: @1.21gigawatts As long as they're otherwise high quality questions, and they're scoped so that the answers won't change, they should be ok.