# ISFDB pointer needed?

Tags: feature-request

Wouldn't it be helpful to put a pointer to the ISFDB somewhere where new users will see it? Putting it on the About page or the Tag Wiki probably wouldn't do much good. Maybe in the "How to Ask" guidelines that you see when you post a question?

Answer (score 2):

Technically, it's already indirectly referenced on the [help > on-topic page](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). The first off-topic point is

> - Facts easily found on a [reference site](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/403/what-are-standard-internet-reference-sites-for-sf): Who played X in Y?

And the linked meta discussion gives:

> - [**Wikipedia**](http://www.wikipedia.org/), the famous online encyclopedia
> - [**IMDB**, the Internet Movie Database](http://www.imdb.com/), a database about movies and TV shows
> - [**ISFDB**, the Internet Speculative Fiction Database](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/index.cgi), a bibliographic database of written sf

Now, if there is support for it and a good way to add it, we could make it more explicit.