# Should the FAQ be updated to remove all traces of General Reference?

Tags: feature-request, site-faq

The [On Topic section of the FAQ](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) reads:

> Not all questions have a home on Stack Exchange. Please note the following types of questions are off-topic here:
>
> - Facts easily found on a [reference site](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/403/what-are-standard-internet-reference-sites-for-sf): Who played X in Y?

which links to a meta question about "Standard Internet Reference Sites" - sites that were used for the line of General Reference.

Seeing as that [General Reference has been burninated](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2545/5184), it seems like we should remove this bullet point from the FAQ.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, we should remove all traces of General Reference ASAP. We voted to eliminate General Reference and the site and FAQ should reflect this accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

**One of two things should happen.**

- 1) We should remove the reference from the FAQ. If General Reference is [no longer an accepted close reason](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2400/should-we-burninate-general-reference?lq=1), it makes no sense to list it on the FAQ.

or

- 2) We should reinstate General Reference as a close reason to match the FAQ.

Since there seems little appetite for #2, #1 should be enacted immediately.

Answer (score 0):

I totally forgot that I'd posted to that dupe question.  I just edited the FAQ to remove this line.