# Comic Book Rant and Counterfactual Questions or How does Superman clip his toe nails?

Tags: discussion

Without getting into a debate over whether comic book questions belong here are not... There has been a recent spate of what I would consider "silly" questions:

- [Can She-Hulk's hair be cut?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/5393/can-she-hulks-hair-be-cut)
- [How does Superman fly?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/5396/how-does-superman-fly)
- [How does Superman shave?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/5394/how-does-superman-shave)

I'm wondering how useful are these types of questions. Consider that:

- Many have multiple, even contradictory answers
- Comic book histories seem to be infinitely malleable in a way that most other works are not
- One could get carried away by asking minor variations of the same question to the point of absurdity

Comment: Typically these kinds of silly questions are only as good as the people answering them. There have been a lot of really dumb questions on this site that have genius answers. If these are getting lots of one-line silly answers. Flag them. We'll convert them to comments for you.

Answer (score 10):

Exploring the untrodden corners of sfnal works and universes is what this site is all about. After all, our [elevator pitch](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/190/what-is-scifi-ses-elevator-pitch/212#212) is

> Behind the scenes and between the lines

This is a fan site. One man's trivia beneath notice is another man's all-important loose thread.

Answer (score 4):

I don't see any of these questions as silly.

Each one had a fundamental "What are these characters limits?" question in them and each question has spawned a new understanding of who the character in question is.

We've learned that She-Hulk isn't infact indestructable.

We've learned that there have been measures created by the comic writers to explain certain aspects that went unanswered for a long time.

We've learned that there are logical answers to unlogical comics that work within the confines of the material.

As for mirroring the questions to infinitum, if someone else were to ask "How does Superman wash his clothes?" it could be argued that it be closed for duplicate or non-constructive questions.

And for that matter, how DOES Superman wash his clothes?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand why it would be difficult for him to wash them. A better question is, do they get dirty? If we are talking about the costume that is made from his blanket.

Comment: If they do get dirty, how does a stain get out? a bullet can't penetrate the suit, so can water?

Comment: Make it a question...

Comment: I find the question trivial myself, lol. But you can go ahead and ask it.